# Predicting from the posterior of a random coefficients model

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, posterior

I've got a model that looks like this:

$$Y_{ig} = \left(\beta_{everyone} + \beta_g\right)X_{ig} + Z_{ig}'\gamma + \epsilon_{ig}$$

in R, this is

```
library(lme4)
example = lmer(Y~ X + Z + (0 + X|g))
```

I want a conditional estimated distribution of $Y|G=g,X=x,Z=z$

For lm, gam, etc, this is just `predict(example)` as the mean of a normal distribution with the same variance as the residuals of the model divided by n-k.

Is there anything different in a mixed model/random coefficients case?  I don't think MCMC is appropriate, as I don't want to estimate the probability of being ins a certain group $g$ -- I want a distribution for a certain $g$.

If indeed the same intuition is applicable, how would I code this?

I'm relatively new to mixed effects models, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the section labeled "Predictions and/or confidence (or prediction) intervals on predictions" on this [page](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) might give you some hints.